# How to add edit text in native Tizen app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I try to understand the GUI creation in native Tizen app. Now I can add label and button. But I cannot find any solution how to add text edit (android TextEdit).

The button I add by below code:

```
   ad->button = elm_button_add(ad->box1);
   evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->button, "clicked", btn_clicked_cb, ad);
   evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(button, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, 0.1);
   evas_object_size_hint_align_set(button, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
   elm_object_text_set(ad->button, "Preform");
   evas_object_show(ad->button);
   elm_box_pack_end(ad->box1, ad->button);
```

so I try to search elm_edit_text_add function but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for a single line **Entry** (TextEdit equivalent):

```
    Evas_Object *entry;
    Evas_Object *layout;
    Evas_Object *scroller;
    Evas_Object *box;
    Evas_Object *nf = data;

    scroller = elm_scroller_add(nf);

    box = elm_box_add(scroller);
    evas_object_size_hint_align_set(box, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.0);
    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(box, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, 0.0);
    elm_object_content_set(scroller, box);

    layout = elm_layout_add(box);
    elm_layout_file_set(layout, ELM_DEMO_EDJ, "entry_layout");
    evas_object_size_hint_align_set(layout, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.0);
    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(layout, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, 0.0);

    entry = elm_entry_add(layout);
    elm_entry_single_line_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
    elm_entry_scrollable_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
    eext_entry_selection_back_event_allow_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(entry, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
    evas_object_size_hint_align_set(entry, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
    evas_object_smart_callback_add(entry, "activated", entry_activated_cb, NULL);
    elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "entry_part", entry);

    elm_box_pack_end(box, layout);
    evas_object_show(layout);
```

For more types of entries look at the examples provided with the tizen SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add edit text and various other fields available is as follows.

Create a `UI Builder - Navigation` / `UI Builder - Single View` application.

File -> New -> Project -> Tizen -> Tizen Native Project -> Template -> UI Builder - Navigation -> Enter project name and click Finish.

In `layout` folder, you will see layout.xml file.

In Palette of layout.xml, add a "`Entry`" from `Input UI Components` by drag drop in "`Design`" of storyboard.