# Tizen 4: Why is a box container not able to hold another layout?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I create a box container on Tizen 4.0:

```
Evas_Object* box = elm_box_add(naviframe);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(box, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(box, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
evas_object_show(box);
elm_object_content_set(naviframe, box);
```

Then I want to add a layout from edje into the box:

```
Evas_Object* page = elm_layout_add(box);
elm_layout_file_set(page, "layout.edj", "groupname_in_layout");
evas_object_show(page);
elm_box_pack_end(box, page);
```

Then I push the box into the screen:

```
elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, NULL, NULL, NULL, box, "empty");
```

**But the layout is not displaying on the emulator.**

However, if I just simply add the layout to the naviframe (and not to the box), **it's displayed**:

```
//elm_box_pack_end(box, page); 
elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, NULL, NULL, NULL, page, "empty");
```

**It is also displayed** if I programmatically create a label and put it into the box:

```
Evas_Object* text = elm_label_add(box);
elm_object_text_set(text, "<align=center>Hello Tizen</align>");
evas_object_show(text);
elm_box_pack_end(box, text);

elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, NULL, NULL, NULL, box, "empty");
```

Why on Earth denies a Box layout to contain the only reasonable layout in Tizen (*Layout*)?? Especially after reading their "*docs*":

> You can add any Evas object to the box.

Based on my knowledge, "any" means any: so a *Layout* is also part of the group named "any".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually box *can* contain just you have to set the align and weight of the layout, no matter what the layout definition contains.

Great help from here: [How to add edit text in native Tizen app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965946/how-to-add-edit-text-in-native-tizen-app), thanks @IsaacCisneros.

So I had only add

```
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(page, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.0);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(page, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, 0.0);
```

And now it works.